# explaining complex geometrically

Tags: complex-analysis

Questions from past test that I need help on.

1) If $f(z) = z+1$ and $g(z) = \frac{−1}{z}$, show that $gfg^{−1}(z) = \frac{z}{1−z}$

For this function I was having trouble finding $g^{-1}$ so Ive kind of cheated a bit so first I computed

$fg$ to get $\frac{-(z+1)}{z} g^{-1} = \frac{z}{1−z} \rightarrow g^{-1} = \frac{z^{2}}{-(z+1)(1-z)}$

and then through some computing I got

$g^{-1} = \frac{z^2}{1-z^2}$

I wanted to know is there any other "right" way to approach this problem?

2) Describe in words what $g^{-1}, f, g$, in succession do to the half plane, and hence explain geometrically why $gfg^{-1}$ has fixed point $0$.

For this one, I was thinking that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are reflections about the $y$ axis and the unit circle, and $f$ reflects the plane over the $y$ axis. I'm just not sure if that's correct, and if so why would the origin remain fixed even though $f$ translated it?

Thanks in advance!

I really need help in these questions please and thank you

Comment: That's function composition, not the normal multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;g^2(z)=g\left(\frac{-1}{z}\right)=\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{z}}=z\Longrightarrow g^{-1}=g\ldots$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\overline{\frac{-1}{z}}=\frac{-1}{\overline z}=-\frac{z}{|z|^2}$$

so $\,g\,,\,g^{-1}\,$ "normalize" $\,z\,$ (i.e., maps it to the unit circle) but change its sign...

$\,f\,$ is simply a translation...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $gfg^{-1}(z)=g(f(g^{-1}(z)))$. To get $g^{-1}(z)$, we let $w=-\frac{1}{z}$, and resolve $z$, which gives $z=g^{-1}(w)$.